# Strange output from printf

Tags: c

I have met a strange 9(unexpected) output from `printf` in C.

The code is:

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2
 3  int
 4  main(void) {
 5      printf("%lf", 3.14 - 1e20 + 1e20);
 6  }
```

However, the output is 0.000000.

I do not know how it works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you expect for the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `double` you're trying to print has [53 bits of precision and 11 bits of exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). `1e20` (base 10) is `101 0110 1011 1100 0111 0101 1110 0010 1101 0110 0011 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` in binary (`56BC75E2D63100000` in hex). Your `3.14` is too small to be represented once added to a number of that magnitude. Change the order of operations if you want to work around that. This code:

```
    printf("%f\n", -1e20 + 1e20 + 3.14);
```

Prints `3.140000`.

Comment: *prints 3.140000 on your system

Comment: @M.M - would you expect different behaviour in some case?

Comment: @M.M, Operator associativity is defined for addition in C (left to right)

Comment: Associativity is not the same as order of evaluation.

Comment: Depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and other factors,  `3.14 - 1e20 + 1e20` may also print `3.140000` or a nearby value.  `3.14 - 1e20 + 1e20` may evaluate using `long double`.  IOWs, the value being printed has 53 bits of precision, yet the addition may have been done with more.